# Using Mirroring to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to mirror a SQL Server 2008 R2 database currently in a fail over with the purpose of doing an in place upgrade. I have installed SQL Server 2012 on another machine to serve as my secondary and SQL Server 2012 Express Edition on a third server to serve as my witness. All of the servers are able to communicate with each other on the specified ports via telnet.

The databases all use mixed mode authentication and when installing the SQL Server the same domain accounts were used for the services the SQL Server uses.(Server Agent and the Server itself) The user I am using for the mirror is on the domain, set up as a local admin to the servers, and sysadmin to the SQL Servers.

I have followed several guides on how to set up the mirror. When I use the wizard to try to do this it completes all of the steps and says success on setting up the endpoints. I click on start mirroring and it states that it is unable to connect to the 2012 installation (the server network address "tcp://2012Installation.domain:port" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1418)).

I have copied all of the network addresses and they work with telnet, as well as having the firewalls down. In addition, the 2012 Installation's database cannot be dropped as it is set up for mirroring. I have followed all of the recommendations [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/11/the-server-network-address-tcpsqlserver5023-can-not-be-reached-or-does-not-exist-check-the-network-address-name-and-that-the-ports-for-the-local-and-remote-endpoints-are-operational-microso/) to no avail. The server it is saying it cannot communicate with is the 2012 SQL, which I am trying to mirror stuff too. It is also the box I am using SQL Management Studio on.

What I think may be the issue is that the original 2008 SQL Server was part of a failover cluster, so it has two different names.(One for the cluster and one for the server itself) It appears as though the mirroring stuff is trying to use the cluster name. I have tried using an alter statement to change the listening partner to the server name itself, but that did not work either. Does any one have any idea why this would not work?

Comment: I'd point you here first: http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/troubleshooting-atabasemirroringerror1418, let me know if that helps in any way.

Comment: That link takes me to a 404 error page.

Comment: Weird, how about this: http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/troubleshooting-atabasemirroringerror1418